# A constant vibration is happening in my home. Like a motor is running

Tags: construction, old-house, engineering, vibration

I have 3 story single column load bearing house. Recently I made a room at the terrace. After the construction my house is vibrating all the time. My house is between 2 houses; there is no gap in them. Because of the vibration I feel very anxious; what to do? The contractor is saying it is normal. But I never felt this before. I am attaching a picture of my house (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: what does the contractor say about the source of the vibration?

Comment: Its the mine being dug underneath… :)

Comment: Would get another contractor to check, a well built house/building should not vibrate without cause.  Hopefully external.

Comment: Funny thing about harmonics, sometimes increasing or decreasing a structure’s height might put it at the ideal height and like a tuning fork you can now feel vibrations that may have always been there but now they are amplified

Comment: Can you tell the frequency of the vibration? 50 Hz? 100 Hz? other?

Comment: I wonder if your neighbors feel the vibrations, and if they perceive them to have started when you added your new room.  Or did they know about them before?

Comment: Just a thought, turn all of your power off and see if the vibration goes away, if so you know it is you and not your neighbor. If it is you turn the breakers on one at a time and determine which causes the vibration. At that point you can probably narrow down the noise source.  If it does not go away it is probably your neighbor.

Comment: Do you have a radon mitigation system?

Comment: The contractor is saying a 3 story building has vibration it is normal. But i never felt it before

Comment: No there is no mine dugging.

Comment: I am planning to hire a civil engineer but i am not finding any.

Comment: The neighbour said they don't feel any vibration.

Comment: I have tried all things but vibration is still there, turned off all power

Comment: I think i dont have one

Comment: You indicate it’s a 3 story single column load bearing house. What is single column load bearing? Does the entire house rest on this one column ?

Comment: If it's still there when all of your power is off, it could be a neighbour - fridge, freezer, a/c, so you need to ask them to turn off their power to check.

Comment: No, all house weight is on the bricks, with a single column from the middle of the house, it is also taking some weight.

Comment: Because your house directly abuts 2 others, it might have nothing to do with your house at all. It could be that either of the neighbors made a change and that vibration is transmitting through the wall from their place to yours. Because of the exact specifics of their construction, they might not feel the vibration at all, but you do. Ask either side to see if they made any changes recently. It could be that it was always there and now with your addition, you now feel it (see @EdBeal's comment about harmonics).

Comment: Thinking about what's NEW that could cause this: My first suspicion, if you have new air ducts for heating or air conditioning or a new air handler, would be oscillations by the duct walls or the machine (fan, blower, pump, whatever you call it) vibrating due to an imbalanced part.    My second suspicion would be the new roof, or part of it perhaps having a not-quite-rigid area that is vibrating.  If your neighbors aren't affected it's more likely something impacting the air space in the new room than coming up from the ground.

Comment: @SouravSaha any update to this interesting problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without being on site, it's going to be very difficult for anyone to identify where the vibration is coming from in order to offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

possibly a harmonic tremor? I have seen it rip bridges apart...has something to do with certain vibrations and wavelengths of the vibrations. When they are tuned just right they can be quite destructive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to measure vibration

Vibration meter is an app called seismograph or seismometer

Can be a smartphone app, or a sensor that's got Bluetooth enabled for you to collect the data. ( https://blog.endaq.com/6-ways-to-measure-vibrations )

Then you can measure in your room, and in shared spaces and at your neighbor's.

Btw, is it constant? Does it go away at night?

I would be concerned, it may cause cracks in the building walls - either internal or external - where specifically depends on the geometry. If measurements are taken then this may help to fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).